# Excel (Version 1902) macro - Querytables to fetch data from website is working super slow

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to get data from web data table and write that into excel sheet.
Was using this code for more than a year. Recently (from Jan 2020) updates (Current version 1902, Build 11328.20492), code is working very slow - more than 10 mins (it used to take 2-3 secs) or not responding most of the time.

```
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Sheets("Data").Range("C1:AA200").Clear
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=ws.Range("C1"))

  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  .SaveData = True

End With
```

Tried to debug...debugger also stuck on `.Refresh BackgroundQuery: = False`

Comment: It might be a good idea to state which version and build code you previously had that was running the code faster before updating or in the case that you don't know, say so or try to guess a range.

Comment: I was wondering if there is any setting in connection url , that can solve this issue. or if there is an alternate way to load data from web table into excel